# 550 Action not taken (in reply to end of DATA command))

Tags: postfix-mta

i got this when i check my postfix logs everything was alright i didnt make any changes in my server just some iptables now when i send an text email everything is ok and the status of email is sent the problem when i send an email with any hyperlink my dsn=5.0.0 bounced!

```
Jan 26 15:58:31 mail postfix/smtp[2075]: D4B1024C21: to=<stimpack47@aol.fr>, relay=mailin-02.mx.aol.com[64.12.137.162]:25, delay=0.62, delays=0.1/0.01/0.32/0.2, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mailin-02.mx.aol.com[64.12.137.162] said: 550 Action not taken (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

here is my config of postfix

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = all
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = mydomain.co
myhostname = mail.mydomain.co
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, myip
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name ($mail_version)
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Answer (score 1):

As your log clearly shows, the OTHER SIDE of the SMTP conversation tells you this.
If this other side is a receiving SMTP *server*, then they are rejecting your message.

It is a proper 5xx response, telling postfix to bounce the message.

Only the OTHER SIDE can shed ligt on whether or not this was in error, or in fact the desired outcome.

Comment: @KirmyOmar Or Are your SMTP connections intercepted by an anti-virus system?